# How to send Cropped image from Ajax to Symfony Controller?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.4

I've been stuck with the image crop in Symfony. I'm using Croppie js to crop , but I'm not able to save the cropped image into the database..

```
<script>  

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
enableExif: true,
viewport: {
  width:200,
  height:200,
  type:'square' 
},
boundary:{
  width:300,
  height:300
}
  });
      $('#upload_image').on('change', function(){
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
  $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
    url: event.target.result
  }).then(function(){
    console.log('jQuery bind complete');
  });
}
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
$('#uploadimageModal').modal('show');
  });
    $('.crop_image').click(function(event){
$image_crop.croppie('result', {
  type: 'canvas',
  size: 'viewport'

}).then(function(response){

   var file = response.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
var data = new FormData();
data.append('img', file);
console.log(file);


  $.ajax({

    url: "{{ path('app_bundle_route') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success:  function(data){
           $('#uploadimageModal').modal('hide');
           $("#previewImg").attr('src', response);

    }
  });
});
 });

});
```

How to get the cropped image in the controller?
Is there anything wrong in the code?

```
console.log(file);
```

---

```
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…
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is cropped, but I can see that you send a file by ajax.

You can get files, request attributes, etc in symfony by using `Request` class.

```
$request->files->get('name_of_your_parameter_sent')
```

If you are not sure what is the name of the parameter sent

```
$request->files->all()
```

More info here [Http foundation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/http_foundation.html)

Comment: Is my Code correct? because I did the same but seems it's not working?  $file = $request->files->get('ïmg'); var_dump($file); gives NULL

Comment: try <form action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">